# WPBakery - Text Font Size Tiny When Page Viewed on Phone

Tags: wordpress, mobile, desktop, wpbakery

Why is the text font size tiny when viewing my page, built with WPBakery, on a phone, but the same page displays fine on the desktop?

Do I really need to explicitly set the text size for each category of device (e.g. desktop, tablet portrait, tablet landscape, smartphone portrait, smartphone landscape)?

It seems the page, when viewed on a phone, is displayed as if it is a desktop, regardless of what I do with the columns.

What am I missing please?

Comment: Could the Wizard WordPress theme I am using potentially be undermining the column changes I am making?

Comment: Please provide some more specific details or code snippets of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some themes like *Avada* come with a **sensitivity** setting to control how slowly text will shrink as the device *viewport* shrinks. Check to see if you have this setting in your theme. Look at the responsive section or ask your theme support team.

Alternatively, if you are comfortable with CSS. Read up on font-size units. Maybe try adjusting your current font-size unit from **px** to either **rem** or **em** (relative units instead of fixed).

**Example**

```
    /* CSS */
    body {
      font-size: 16px; /* Fixed base size. */
    }
    .responsive-text {
      font-size: 2rem; /* Relative to base size. 2x larger. */
    }

    <!-- HTML -->
    <div class="responsive-text">
      Hey, check me out! I don't shrink much on a mobile.
    </div>
```

Read all the gory details here  https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-size/